# Set height of iFrame dynamically not working

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Here I have two iframe what I have to do is that, I've to change the height of iframe after window.load. But In this case the I get the height which is the height of the last iframe.

For example: After window load I get

1st iframe height is 515px

2nd iframe height is 199px

But the applied height to both iframe `199px` that is the height of second iframe. And if you change the order of the frames like,
1st is 199px and 2nd is 515px

then height is applied to both frames is `515px`.

So I want to set the height which is the actual height of the frame.

Here is my code from where you can get idea. You can check the console where height is printed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <iframe
      src="https://embed.kooapp.com/embedKoo?kooId=91f35ac5-dd15-4271-bb36-b9793131399a"
      name="kooFrame"
      id="1"
      ></iframe>
      <iframe
      src="https://embed.kooapp.com/embedKoo?kooId=803857a6-2a9d-4c70-9731-69213e80fbf0"
      name="kooFrame"
      id="2"
      ></iframe>
      
      <script>
        const iframe = document.getElementsByName('kooFrame');
      window.onload = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < iframe.length; i++) {

    const ifrm = document.getElementById(i + 1);
    ifrm.scrolling = 'no';
    ifrm.frameBorder = 0;
    ifrm.allowFullScreen = true;
    ifrm.allowTransparency = true;
    ifrm.style.width = '100%';
    ifrm.contentWindow.postMessage('FrameHeight', '*');
    let lastData = '';

    window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      console.log('Line----68 index.html', event.data)      
      if(lastData !== event.data.FrameHeight){
        if (event.data.hasOwnProperty('FrameHeight')) {
        ifrm.style.height = `${event.data.FrameHeight}px`;
        lastData = event.data.FrameHeight
      }
      }
    });
  }
}
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```